# Problem of integration krakend with keycloak

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, api-gateway, krakend

I have keycloak bitnami chart and krakend deployed in in k8s. Also I have a test api, and I want being authenticated before access it. I'm able to get valid jwt token from keycloak, but when I'm trying to access my api through krakend, it returns 401 error
Any help is really appreciated.

Software versions:
keycloak: 16.1.1
crakend: 2.0.4

```
{
  "$schema": "https://www.krakend.io/schema/v3.json",
  "version": 3,
  "timeout": "3000ms",
  "cache_ttl": "300s",
  "output_encoding": "json",
  "port": 8080,
  "endpoints": [
      {
          "endpoint": "/mock/parents/{id}",
          "method": "GET",
          "input_headers": [
             "Authorization"
           ],
          "extra_config": {
              "auth/validator": {
                  "alg": "RS256",
                  "jwk-url": "http://keycloak-headless:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
                  "disable_jwk_security": true,
                  "roles_key_is_nested": true,
                  "roles_key": "realm_access.roles",
                  "roles": ["test-app-parent"],
                  "operation_debug": true
              }
          },
          "output_encoding": "json",
          "concurrent_calls": 1,
          "backend": [
              {
                  "url_pattern": "/parents/{id}",
                  "encoding": "json",
                  "sd": "static",
                  "extra_config": {},
                  "host": [
                    "http://testapp-service:8400"
                  ],
                  "disable_host_sanitize": false,
                  "blacklist": [
                      "super_secret_field"
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "url_pattern": "/siblings/{id}",
                  "encoding": "json",
                  "sd": "static",
                  "extra_config": {},
                  "host": [
                      "http://testapp-service:8400"
                  ],
                  "blacklist": [
                      "sibling_id"
                  ],
                  "group": "extra_info",
                  "disable_host_sanitize": false
              },
              {
                  "url_pattern": "/parents/{id}/children",
                  "encoding": "json",
                  "sd": "static",
                  "extra_config": {},
                  "host": [
                      "http://testapp-service:8400"
                  ],
                  "disable_host_sanitize": false,
                  "mapping": {
                      "content": "cars"
                  },
                  "whitelist": [
                      "content"
                  ]
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "endpoint": "/mock/bogus-new-api/{path}",
          "method": "GET",
          "extra_config": {
              "auth/validator": {
                  "alg": "RS256",
                  "jwk-url": "http://keycloak-headless:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
                  "disable_jwk_security": true
              },
              "github.com/devopsfaith/krakend/proxy": {
                  "static": {
                      "data": {
                          "new_field_a": 123,
                          "new_field_b": [
                              "arr1",
                              "arr2"
                          ],
                          "new_field_c": {
                              "obj": "obj1"
                          }
                      },
                      "strategy": "always"
                  }
              }
          },
          "output_encoding": "json",
          "concurrent_calls": 1,
          "backend": [
              {
                  "url_pattern": "/not-finished-yet",
                  "encoding": "json",
                  "sd": "static",
                  "extra_config": {},
                  "host": [
                      "nothing-here"
                  ],
                  "disable_host_sanitize": false
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
 }
```

Comment: Can your KrakenD container access your 'keycloak-headless' container? If the jwk-url is not accessible from Kraken, then you'll get a 401.

Comment: Yes. For sure, krakend has access to kk

Comment: have you got the fix for this issue. i am also getting the same 401 when try to access backend using api-gateway karkend

Comment: Did you try with following "jwk_url" (removing "auth/")?
http://keycloak-headless:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs
To verify visit the address http://<your-host>/realms/<your-realm>/protocol/openid-connect/certs

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Oh my God this made me go insane.

In one of the last version updates they **changed jwk-url to jwk_url**.

https://github.com/krakendio/krakend-ce/issues/495#issuecomment-1138397005

After I fixed that it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after I changed
`"jwk_url": "http://KEYCLOAK-SERVICE-NAME:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs"` to `"jwk_url": "http://host.docker.internal:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

create new realms role "test-app-parent" and

> > go to user section and assign that roles to that user.
> > you can check from https://jwt.io/ is_your token contain "test-app-parent" this role in "realm_access.roles". like below sample example

"realm_access": {
"roles": [
"default-roles-krakend",
"offline_access",
"**test-app-parent**",
"uma_authorization"
]
}